# Are oprhan blocks paid to miners?

Tags: mining

Are Uncle rewards paid to the miner of the uncle?

These are my logs. I don't understand if I've been paid  after the block I mined is no longer in the canonical chain.

```
INFO [08-20|17:21:19.206] Commit new mining work                   number=10698385 sealhash="4803fb…42ee3d" uncles=1 txs=183  gas=12470845 fees=1.926527275   elapsed=86.735ms
INFO [08-20|17:21:24.207] Commit new mining work                   number=10698385 sealhash="13335e…a82c76" uncles=1 txs=187  gas=12468272 fees=1.939251505   elapsed=87.202ms
INFO [08-20|17:21:24.313] Successfully sealed new block            number=10698385 sealhash="4803fb…42ee3d" hash="2b6ad4…6ff956" elapsed=5.106s
INFO [08-20|17:21:24.313]  mined potential block                  number=10698385 hash="2b6ad4…6ff956"
INFO [08-20|17:21:24.314] Commit new mining work                   number=10698386 sealhash="b30adc…38570e" uncles=0 txs=0    gas=0        fees=0             elapsed=1.103ms
INFO [08-20|17:21:24.398] Commit new mining work                   number=10698386 sealhash="a160f7…a4d133" uncles=0 txs=145  gas=12465119 fees=1.667804444   elapsed=85.373ms
INFO [08-20|17:21:24.403] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=203  mgas=12.498  elapsed=89.680ms    mgasps=139.365  number=10698385 hash="e4647d…cd1850" dirty=2.00GiB
INFO [08-20|17:21:29.068] Deep froze chain segment                 blocks=5  elapsed=13.466ms    number=10608384 hash="c48027…1ec23d"
INFO [08-20|17:21:29.395] Commit new mining work                   number=10698386 sealhash="8683a5…321120" uncles=0 txs=135  gas=12473957 fees=1.744267335   elapsed=81.889ms
INFO [08-20|17:21:34.399] Commit new mining work                   number=10698386 sealhash="af0df6…1ce794" uncles=0 txs=149  gas=12458243 fees=1.809310246   elapsed=85.763ms
INFO [08-20|17:21:39.404] Commit new mining work                   number=10698386 sealhash="585b75…34befd" uncles=0 txs=169  gas=12454774 fees=1.836050483   elapsed=90.217ms
INFO [08-20|17:21:44.400] Commit new mining work                   number=10698386 sealhash="fae165…b25ce9" uncles=0 txs=168  gas=12457487 fees=1.868399904   elapsed=86.097ms
INFO [08-20|17:21:49.517] Commit new mining work                   number=10698386 sealhash="a5a85c…719e4b" uncles=0 txs=156  gas=12462725 fees=1.889301565   elapsed=191.608ms
INFO [08-20|17:21:49.535] Chain reorg detected                     number=10698383 hash="d35252…e339a5" drop=2 dropfrom="2b6ad4…6ff956" add=3 addfrom="5142c0…e4e94e"
INFO [08-20|17:21:49.543] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=147  mgas=12.509  elapsed=396.652ms   mgasps=31.536   number=10698386 hash="5142c0…e4e94e" dirty=2.00GiB
INFO [08-20|17:21:49.544] Commit new mining work                   number=10698387 sealhash="e6c015…ae12e8" uncles=0 txs=0    gas=0        fees=0             elapsed="535.313µs"
INFO [08-20|17:21:49.683] Commit new mining work                   number=10698387 sealhash="b2624f…1b18e1" uncles=0 txs=137  gas=12484353 fees=1.710992588   elapsed=140.234ms
INFO [08-20|17:21:54.610] Commit new mining work                   number=10698387 sealhash="1c82e2…affc07" uncles=0 txs=147  gas=12479437 fees=1.792299693   elapsed=66.528ms
INFO [08-20|17:21:59.633] Commit new mining work                   number=10698387 sealhash="9f4696…d7f0dd" uncles=0 txs=178  gas=12489107 fees=1.892902982   elapsed=89.140ms
INFO [08-20|17:22:04.143] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=187  mgas=12.488  elapsed=113.661ms   mgasps=109.867  number=10698387 hash="293f14…cc4a21" dirty=2.00GiB
```

As you can see, my node detected a 3 block reorg from 10698386 to 10698383 just after I mined block 1069838. I would like to know if in this conditions I've been paid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Initially yes - as soon as a miner completes any block he gets its block reward.

But the reward is only useful if it's valid in the *canonical* chain. For an orphan block there is no parent so it's not part of the canonical chain in any sense. So in theory the miner gets the reward for the orphan block but no other miner recognizes the block as part of the canonical chain so the reward is useless - it could only be utilized in a chain which includes that block.

So, for all practical purposes, the answer is **no**.

Comment: I'll add that an orphan block it is likely to became an uncle if its parent is in the main chain. If his parent isn't in the main chain or it is an uncle then it will not receive any reward.